# Axios doesn't return response after successful submisson in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Im making a simple login system using Express, React and passport. Axios executes submission and successfully communicates with express and User is succesfully serialized into session. However, the code isn't executed in *.then()* part of Axios call. I get no error, it just doesn't do anything

**client/components/Login.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import '../css/components.css';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import {useEffect,useState} from "react";
import Axios from "axios";

const styles = {
    h2Login: {
        textAlign: "center",
        fontSize: "25px"
    },
    divLogin: {
        textAlign:"center",
        paddingTop: "15px"
    },
    loginA: {
        fontSize: "15px"
    },
    margins: {
        marginTop: "5px"
    }
}

function Login(){

    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const [loginUsername, setLoginUsername] = useState("")
    const [loginPassword, setLoginPassword] = useState("")

    const login = () => {
        Axios({
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                username: loginUsername,
                password: loginPassword,
            },
            withCredentials: true,
            url: "http://localhost:4000/login",
        }).then((res) => { // It's like this isn't even called
                console.log(res); 
                if(res.status === 200){
                    console.log("Successfully logged in");
                    navigate('/');
                }else if(res.status === 500){
                    console.log("Failed to log in: " +  res)
                }

            }

        );
    };



    return(
        <section className="justify-content-center" >
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                    <div className="col-lg-8">
                        <div>
                            <div className="form-input login-form">
                                <h2 style={styles.h2Login}>Login Form</h2>
                                <form className="login-form">
                                    <div className="form-group">
                                        <input className="form-control  form-control-md input-thingy" type="text" placeholder="username" id="email"
                                               onChange={(e) => setLoginUsername(e.target.value)}
                                        />

                                    </div>
                                    <div className="form-group ">
                                        <input className="form-control input-thingy" type="password" placeholder="password" id="password"
                                           onChange={(e) => setLoginPassword(e.target.value)}
                                        />

                                    </div>

                                        <button style={styles.margins} type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={login}>Login</button>

                                    <div style={styles.divLogin}>
                                        <a style={styles.loginA} className=""
                                            >Don't
                                            have an account?</a>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}



export default Login;
```

**client/app.js**

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Nav from "./components/Nav.js";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "./components/Login.js"
import Axios from "axios";
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <header>
                    <Nav/>
                    <Routes>
                        <Route path='/login' element={<Login/>} />
                    </Routes>
                </header>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );

}
export default App
```

**server/server.js**

```js
if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {require('dotenv').config();}
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const initializePassport = require('./passport-config');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const methodOverride = require('method-override');
const app = express();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
//const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
//app.use(cookieParser({secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});




// Cors
const whitelist = process.env.WHITELISTED_DOMAINS
    ? process.env.WHITELISTED_DOMAINS.split(",")
    : []

const corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"))
        }
    },
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

// knex & bookshelf
const knex = require('knex')({
    client: "mysql",
    connection: {
        host: "localhost",
        user: "dbuser",
        password: "dbpass",
        database: "testdb"
    }
});
const bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

async function createBookshelfOf(tbl){
    return bookshelf.Model.extend({
        tableName: tbl,
        idAttribute: "id"
    });
}

async function insertInto(table, obj){
    await knex(table).insert(obj)
        .then(()=>console.log("INSERTED: " + obj + ", INTO table: " + table))
        .catch((err)=>{console.log(err); throw err;})
}

// Passport
initializePassport(
    passport,
    async username=>{
        try{
            let bookshelfUser = await createBookshelfOf("Users");
            return await new bookshelfUser().where("username", username).fetch().then((data)=>{
                return data.attributes;
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return null;
        }},
    async id=>{
        try{
            let bookshelfUser = await createBookshelfOf("Users");
            return await new bookshelfUser().where("idUsers", id).fetch().then((data)=>{
                return data.attributes;
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            return null;
        }});

// Don't know what it does, but somehow without it passport doesn't work so DON'T TOUCH IT

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});

/* Session*/
app.use(session({
    secret : process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized : false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride('__method'));

// Authentication

app.post('/login', (req, res, next)=>{
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect : '/',
        failureRedirect  : '/login'
    }, (err, user, info)=>{
        if(err){res.status(500).send(err); return;}
        if(!user){
            res.status(500).send("Could not fetch user");
            return;
        }
        req.logIn(user, (err)=>{
            if(err){return next(err)}
            res.status(200).send(user);
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});


function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
    next();
}

app.post("/register", checkNotAuthenticated, async(req, res) => {
    try{
        let Users = await createBookshelfOf("Users");
        let users = await new Users().fetchAll()
        for (let user of users.toJSON()){
            if (user.username === req.body.username){
                res.status(500).send("Username exists")
                return
            }
        }
        const hashedPassword = bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
        let obj = [{
            username: req.body.username,
            name: "Test",
            surname: "Test",
            password: hashedPassword
        }];

        insertInto("Users", obj);
        res.status(200).send("Successfully inserted data")

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message)
        res.status(500).send(e.message);

    }
});

app.get('/user', (req, res)=>{
    res.status(200).send(req.user);
})


// Server config

const PORT = 4000; // backend routing port
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

**server/passport-config.js**

```js
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

function initialize(passport, getUserByUsername, getUserById) {

    console.log("Passport initialized");

    const authenticateUser = async (username, password, done) => {
        const user = await getUserByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            console.log("No user with that username");
            return done(null, false, { message: 'No user with that username' });

        }

        try {
            console.log(user);
            await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, result)=>{
                if (!result){
                    console.log("Password incorrect");
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
                }
                if(result){
                    console.log("User logged in successfully: " + user.username);
                    return done(null, user);
                }
                });

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            return done(e)
        }
    }



    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'username' }, authenticateUser));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.idUsers));
    passport.deserializeUser(async(id, done) => {
        return done(null, await getUserById(id));
    })
}


module.exports = initialize
```

Comment: `I get no error` It doesn't look like you have a `catch`, so you might want to try that first. `Axios(/* */).then(/* */).catch(error => { console.log(error) })`

Answer (score 2):

Axios() returns a promise.
If the promise is successful the then block gets executed
If it fails catch block gets executed

```
Axios() 
.then()
.catch((err) =>{
console.log(err) 
})
```

Comment: So I can't handle different response codes? For example if I want to treat bad request, forbidden or internal server error differently?

Comment: Axios will reject the request promise if the response status code is one of 4xx Or 5xx error codes gets returned from the server.
Hence the catch block will get executed. You can read the err object and decide the next step